# Pcap_inject sends too many messages

Tags: c, pcap, wifi

I am trying to send authenticate messages to an access point, but when I do that it sends 15 authenticate messages to the AP, whereby the AP doesn't respond. I use a Mac OS X and the libpcap library.

Here is my code:

```
int inject(char *src_mac, char *dst_mac)
{
     int i, rc;
    char *device, *packet;
    char error[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t *handle;

    device = pcap_lookupdev(error);
    handle = pcap_create(device, error);
    check(device != NULL, "Failed to find a device!");
    check(handle != NULL, "Failed to create handle!");

    rc = pcap_set_rfmon(handle, 1);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed to set monitor mode!");
    rc = pcap_set_promisc(handle, 1);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed to set promiscuous mode!");
    rc = pcap_activate(handle);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed to activate handle!");
    rc = pcap_datalink(handle);
    check(rc == DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO, "Failed to use the correct format!");

    packet = radiotap_setup(src_mac, dst_mac,\
                        dst_mac, 0xb0);
    rc = pcap_inject(handle, packet,\
            RADIO_LEN + sizeof(ieee80211_hdr));
    check(rc != -1, "Failed to send packet!");

    pcap_close(handle);
    return 1;

   error:
    pcap_close(handle);
    return -1;
}

char *radiotap_setup(char *dst_mac, char *src_mac, char *bssid_mac, int fc)
{
    int i, radio_len;
    unsigned int shost_mac[6], dhost_mac[6], bhost_mac[6];
     static char packet[RADIO_LEN + sizeof(ieee80211_hdr)];
    ieee80211_hdr ieeeh;

    ieeeh.fc = fc;
     ieeeh.dur = 314;
     sscanf(src_mac, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &shost_mac[0], &shost_mac[1],\
          &shost_mac[2], &shost_mac[3], &shost_mac[4], &shost_mac[5]);
     sscanf(dst_mac, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &dhost_mac[0], &dhost_mac[1],\
          &dhost_mac[2], &dhost_mac[3], &dhost_mac[4], &dhost_mac[5]);
    sscanf(bssid_mac, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &bhost_mac[0], &bhost_mac[1],\
          &bhost_mac[2], &bhost_mac[3], &bhost_mac[4], &bhost_mac[5]);

    for (i = 0; i != 6; i++) {
        ieeeh.src[i] = (unsigned char)shost_mac[i];
        ieeeh.dest[i] = (unsigned char)dhost_mac[i];
        ieeeh.bssid[i] = (unsigned char)bhost_mac[i];
    }
    ieeeh.seq = rand();
     ieeeh.rc = 1792;

    radio_len = RADIO_LEN;
    memcpy(&packet[2], &radio_len, 2);
    memcpy(packet + RADIO_LEN, &ieeeh,\
          sizeof(ieee80211_hdr));

     return packet;
}
```

When I execute the code I get this on Wireshark:
[Wireshark output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQXuA.png)

Comment: I can't find any documentation for `radiotap_setup` online. Is that a function you defined?

Comment: Yes it is, I am sorry I should have mentioned that

Comment: Could you add it to the original post? I don't understand what it's supposed to do; you call it twice. The rest of the code looks ok.

Comment: It’s just makes a 802.11 header and a radiotap header

Comment: Do you know what is wrong? I have it also when I use tools like reaver.

Comment: Well, if you have the same issue with other tools, it's probably not coming from the tool itself... On what interface are you emitting? What's the interface configuration?

Comment: I use the AirPort Extreme, the built-in interface from OS X.

Comment: I first had it only with reaver and this program authenticated just normally, but when I tried to add the associating part, I got this

Comment: I know now what the problem is, but not the solution. The problem is that the retry flag from the Frame control field in the IEEE 802.11 header is enabled. So I disabled it in the radio setup function, but it retransmitted still and the next packets was the retry flag again enabled. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, but rather another effect of the real issue. According to the documentation, the retry flag is set for retransmitted frames. Frames are retransmitted if your endpoint doesn't receive an answer. Maybe the AP doesn't answer because there's an issue with your auth. frame? Have you compared it with reaver's auth. frame?

Comment: Thanks for the help btw, but have you seen the time between the authentication frames, the AP could never answer so fast. On Wireshark I have the same auth frame as reaver has and as the normal authentication, but the auth messages after the first are the same but have the reply flag enabled. That is the only difference.